# iOS @IBOutlet views all be nil only in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xib

I'm using `Xcode8` and worked on a OC mix swift project

With my new `viewController` in my project I'm using `swift 2.3`
I create the `ViewController` simply by creating new file and with (Also crate XIB file) checked (so it could auto binding the VC
Since My past codes is OC so I init my VC with

```
_theViewController = [[TheViewController alloc] init];
```

and want to set frame or other init thing with the `@IBOutlet` views

It worked all well (the xib loaded as expect and after break in **viewDidLoad** I could see those Outlet instance(not nil)in iOS 9 and +

but under iOS 8 whenever in `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear`  `viewDidAppear` those `IBOutlet` views always be nil, And after I comment all init thing,It seems it just not load my `xib` view as I want

I've tried some solutions I could find but seems not worked(I'm sure xib is linked with VC.(it created and linked by xcode after all) overriding some function or some other ways hope for force loading it )

**any suggestion will be appreciated  T_T**

PS: I'm not using storyboard ,just using this xib tech 4 quick and viewable development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To initialize a view controller object using a nib file, create your view controller class programmatically and initialize it using the `init(nibName:bundle:)` method.

When its views are requested, the view controller loads them from the nib file.

API reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: so, I was wrong all the time.  when I simply run [alloc init] int iOS 9+ auto do `init(nibName:bundle:)` things 4 me ?  Or even my implements worked in iOS 9+ should I replace all my init with the `init(nibName:bundle:)` int this situation ?